# HIbernate and eager loading of collections

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a 1-many relationship between class `A` and class `B`, represented by a foreign key relation between two tables in the database.  and I want hibernate to eagerly load the collection of `B`s so that it can be traversed outside a session.

So I specify `lazy="false"` on both the one-to-many and many-to-one mapping entry.

`B.hbm` :

```
<many-to-one cascade="all" fetch="join" lazy="false"
   class="A" name="...">
   <column name="adgroup_id"/>
  </many-to-one>
```

`A.hbm`

```
<list cascade="all" inverse="true" name="..." lazy="false" fetch="join">
      <key column="adgroup_id" />
       <one-to-many class="B"  />
</list>
```

I notice that the sql executed by hibernate indeed returns the expected number of rows, but when I call

`A.getBs()`, I get too many elements. Indeed, since my ids in the database are auto-assigned, it seems to return n+1 elements where n is the currently highest id in the table of `B`s.

What is going on here ?

I am using the Spring hibernate template btw, calling `template.get(class,id)` to return the `A`

Answer (score -4):

Very good description of n+1 problem: [What is SELECT N+1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem)

Comment: Sorry, I fail to see how your answer is useful. Only a single select is performed here, returning the expected number of rows. However, the number of entries in the returned collection in Java I get too many elements